# ggplot two side by side graphs with the same scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create two side by side graphs to compare the values (one absolute values and one proportions). I managed to create some simple graphs, but I cannot figure out if I have to wrap them or use a grid? I just keep getting errors.

My data looks something like this:

```
recent_quarter <- c(12, 15, 2, 3)
all_data <- c(218, 323, 34, 12)
recent_perc <- c(38,47,6,9)
all_perc <- c(37,55,4,5)
gender <- factor(c("M", "F", "Unknown", "Other"),
              levels = c("M", "F", "Unknown", "Other"))

df <- data.frame(gender, all_data, recent_quarter, all_perc, 
                 recent_perc, all_data)
```

Then I created a simple plot

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = gender, y = recent_perc)) +
  geom_col(fill = "gray70") +
  theme_minimal()
```

For this one, I'd like to add a second plot with the all_perc as the y axis. I'm stumped on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

```r
g1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = gender, y = recent_perc)) +
  geom_col(fill = "gray70") +
  theme_minimal() 
g2 <- g1 + aes(y=all_perc)
cowplot::plot_grid(g1,g2)
```

`gridExtra` (as referenced in @Josh's answer) and `patchwork` are two other ways to do the grid assembly.

Or:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(gender, all_data, recent_quarter, all_perc, all_data, recent_perc)
df_long <- df %>% 
    select(gender, ends_with("perc")) %>% 
    pivot_longer(-gender) ## creates 'name', 'value' columns
ggplot(df_long, aes(gender, value)) + geom_col() +
   facet_wrap(~name)
```

Comment: Ah perfect, thank you! The second one works well. The first one leaves the two different scales but the second one seems to have the y axis the same which makes them comparable.

Answer (score 0):

install  the package gridExtra and use:

```
grid.arrange(
ggplot(df, aes(x = gender, y = recent_perc)) +
  geom_col(fill = "gray70") +
  theme_minimal(), 
ggplot(df, aes(x = gender, y = all_perc)) +
  geom_col(fill = "gray70") +
  theme_minimal(), 
ncol = 2)
```

Comment: This works, but it gives two different scales on the y axis and doesn't allow for comparison.

Comment: adjust using +ylim(0, whaterver numer) for each ggplot